# Sefer on Igros Moshe

Tags: jewish-books, machlokes, moshe-feinstein

I was told that a while back a Sefer came out that went through a couple of the teshuvot in Igros Moshe and refuted some of the answers given. 
Due to some harsh remarks the author made in the introduction the Sefer was put into chayrem (nobody sold it). Im curious as to what the name of the Sefer was. Although the author was out of line for his comments in the introduction, from what I hear the Sefer itself was incredibly thought out. 
Anyone know the sefers name?

Comment: See here for Rav Aviner's view of the sefer (including a relevant incident involving the author and the Steipler and a quote from a leading talmid of R. Moshe): http://www.kipa.co.il/jew/54019.html

Comment: The sefer can be downloaded here: http://www.israel613.com/books/MEANE_IGROT-H.pdf Some of the critique aligns with the views of other poskim (e.g. on Chalav Yisrael, the time of Chatzos, nylon tzitzis etc), and the other parts tend to be less convincing, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work in question is the Ma'aneh L'igrot מענה לאגרות of R. Yom Tov Schwartz.

Comment: The work was relegated to obscurity for good reason. The cover page reads: והוכחתי שהמחבר הזה הכשיל את הרבים באופן מחריד בהתרת הרבה איסורים חמורים וטעה בכל הוראותיו או בדבר משנה או בשקול הדעת וסברא the rest of the work is no more respectfull...

Comment: What's wrong with what he wrote on the cover page? Isn't that the derech ha'Torah - to fight for the truth of the Torah without regard for what might have already been said? And maybe there were instances where Rav Schwarz was right?

Comment: What's wrong is that he was a lesser scholar, while R. Moshe was clearly a gadol hador. Yes, there were instances in which R. Schwartz may have been correct (when his critique aligned with the views of other poskim who disagreed with R. Moshe), but that was no way to write about a scholar far superior to him. To quote non-Orthodox R. Louis Jacobs:

Comment: "The strange book published by Rabbi Yom Tov Halevi Schwartz, Ma’aneh Le’igerot. (New York, 1973) Schwartz’s stated aim in this book is to demolish Feinstein’s standing as a posek, seeking, on the whole quite unsuccessfully, to show that Feinstein is often in error in his halakhic decisions. To the unbiased reader Schwartz cannot hold a candle to Feinstein in halakhic expertise and talmudic learning."

Comment: "This book is a curiosity, too, because Schwartz had resort to the same publisher as the one who published Feinstein’s works and the work at a superficial glance, looks like an additional Feinstein volume since exactly the same format, type and binding is used for both. See the biography of Feinstein, op.cit. p. 192 that the embarrassed publisher consulted Feinstein before publishing the Schwartz book but Feinstein told him to go ahead since his living depended on it."

Comment: @MarkA. The book could have presented the exact same material much much more respectfully. To claim, for example, that R. Feinstein erred in _every single one of his rulings_ is not just your typical fight for the truth of Torah. It is a uniquely nasty personal attempt at smearing גדולים וטובים ממנו.

Comment: @mevaqesh. He was writing that as a guzmah. Rischa di'oraisah. No big deal.

Comment: @MarkA. You are welcome to your opinion. Personally I do not think that this is at all normal ritha d'orayta, and it is difficult for me to imagine that anyone who has actually perused the work, and views it in the context of halakhic literature from the period, would find it consistent with the norm. Indeed, this sentiment was and is shared by numerous talmidei hakhamim of diverse backgrounds, and was the reason for the reaction to the book, which prompted this question. I can only conjecture what drives you to repeatedly defend this vile piece of hate literature.

Comment: @MarkA. I recommend moving further discussion to chat, as it does not seem to belong here.

Comment: available at https://www.bannedseforim.com/